# Displaying feature info in a popup

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I was able to "combine my shapefile and CSV data have made a lot of progress on my project.

Now I want to display the attribute data in a popup when I either click or hover over a country... I've done some goggling and looked at some examples but can't seem to make what I've seen work...

Can someone recommend a link or example I can look at?

I'm using MapServer and OpenLayers

Let me know if you'd like to see my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest checking this openlayers example: [getfeatureinfo-control](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html). It shows the feature info in a table on the page. Putting it into a popup should be easy changing some lines in the javascript.

In general [openlayers.org/dev/examples/](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) is a good resource for openlayers code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the link!! I followed one of the OL examples and got the pop-up box the shows up!!  The problem I'm now having is the box wont close.... When each time I click on the x in upper right corner of a box, another pop-up box appears.... I can figure out whats happening!!  Any ideas as to a sol'n would be gratefully appreciated!!  Chris

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that you are calling your popup creation function in the closeBoxCallback parameter?  This is a snippet from some code I was working on:

```
      popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
             "popup",
             map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy),
             new OpenLayers.Size(300,150),
             "Updating<br/>information...",
             null,
             true,
             null
           );
```

The last null is in the place where you would put a callback function when the closeBox on the popup is clicked.  In what I've displayed above, this is set to null and therefore, nothing is called and the popup doesn't reappear.

I saw in the "Open Popup on Layer.Vector" example in the OL Examples that there's a callback function here "onPopupClose".  That unselects the feature which also I believe calls the onFeatureUnselect, which in turn destroys the popup.  That is all setup in this line of that example:

selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(polygonLayer,
                {onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect});

So, it sounds like you need to either take out the closeBoxCallback in your popup creation (i.e. set it to null) or do something similar to this example that destroys the popup a bit later in the process.